# select distinct rows based on column values

Tags: sql, oracle

In one table i have four columns  'FirstName' , 'LastName' , 'Dob', 'Number'
There are multiple rows for the unique  'first Name' and 'LastName' and they can have same or different  'Number' and 'Dob' values

```
FirstName  LastName   Dob         Number
Alice      Smith      02/03/77    0876543    (require)
Alice      Smith      Null        0876543    (Not require)
Alice      Smith      Null        Null       (Not require)
John       Adam       11/28/63    3265783    (require)
John       Adam       11/28/63    Null       (Not Require)
John       Adam       05/15/58    Null       (require)
Sally      Smith      Null        Null       (require)
```

I want distinct rows, but I need only one record if either the 'Number'or the 'Dob' matches with other records of same FirstName' and 'LastName'
 I am lookin for the rows that are labeled 'require' in the example above. The combinations i tried didn't get results i thought they would.
Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show your desired result set.  And, what if you had `Alice Smith 2000-01-01 0876543` and `Alice Smith 2001-01-01 1234567`?

Comment: How did you end up with this kind of data in a database table? I am asking off of curiosity, not criticism. While you may receive a solution, there might be a better way to organize this dataset to avoid situations like these.

Comment: Which database are you using? Please tag the question with whatever it is. And please show your query, even if it isn't working or even compiling.

Comment: I am using Oracle database. Alice Smith 2000-01-01 0876543 and `Alice Smith 2001-01-01 1234567" both will be required since the records have different number.

Answer (score 0):

I would first select all rows that have all four fields populated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, Dob, Number
FROM customers
WHERE Dob IS NOT NULL And Number IS NOT NULL
```

Then I would add to the selection the records with NOT NULL values that do not exist in the first selection:

```
with RequiredSet as (
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, Dob, Number
FROM customers
WHERE Dob IS NOT NULL And Number IS NOT NULL
), AdditionalSet as (
SELECT distinct c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Dob, c.Number
FROM customers c
WHERE Dob IS NOT NULL And NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
   FROM RequiredSet r 
   WHERE r.FirstName = c.FirstName And r.LastName=c.LastName And r.Dob=c.Dob)
OR Number IS NOT NULL And NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
   FROM RequiredSet r 
   WHERE r.FirstName = c.FirstName And r.LastName=c.LastName And r.Number=c.Number)
)
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Dob, Number
FROM RequiredSet
UNION ALL 
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Dob, Number
FROM AdditionalSet
```

Comment: Thanks, @cha I will give it a try.

Comment: Still getting duplicate rows. Also the query is taking too long. Is it possible to get the count of distinct rows also. Thanks

Comment: You can significantly speed it up if you add the first query RequiredSet to a temp table. And then add the second query to another temp table. I will add a Distinct to the second query that should fix the duplicates